# Cutting a string after occurrence of sub-string in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am writing a Makefile which needs to figure out the directory of an installed program, which can be found in `PATH`; or that is to say, is assumed to be in `PATH`.

For example: if the binary is `/opt/Xilinx/12.1/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/xst`, then the path I am looking for is `/opt/Xilinx/12.1/ISE_DS/ISE`. The program could also be found as `/home/markus/Xilinx/10.1/ISE/bin/lin64/xst` for example. Xilinx included the `ISE_DS` part of the path only in later versions.

As a matter of fact the `/bin/lin64/xst` substring cannot simply be deleted, because it could also be `/bin/lin/xst` depending on your installation.

The Makefile could do something like `XILINX_PATH = $(shell which xst)` and then process this string according to the above example, but I cannot figure out how to do this in a clean way.

The best I could come up with is this:

```
XILINX_PATH_1 = $(shell which xst)
XILINX_PATH_2 = $(subst /bin/lin64/xst,,${XILINX_PATH_1})
XILINX_PATH = $(subst /bin/lin/xst,,${XILINX_PATH_2})
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
XILINX_PATH = $(shell which xst | sed 's%bin\/lin\(64\)*/xst%%')
```

Note that the `*` really ought to be `?` for the sake of tidiness, but I'm having trouble getting that to work. I'll do a few more experiments and post an update if I solve it.

**EDIT:**
Using `\?` instead of `*` works on non-obsolete versions of GNUMAKE (or at least on 3.81) and is more correct.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. This looks so much better.